# Symbol lookup in CMake fails although symbol is present

Tags: cmake, lookup, symbols

I am trying to check whether symbol getaddrinfo_a exists using CMake:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE)
check_symbol_exists(getaddrinfo_a netdb.h HAVE_GETADDRINFO_A)
list(REMOVE_ITEM CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE)
```

While getaddrinfo_a is defined in netdb.h (given that _GNU_SOURCE is defined), CMake fails to find it:

```
-- Looking for getaddrinfo_a
-- Looking for getaddrinfo_a - not found.
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you need to set up `CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES`?

Comment: netdb.h is on the standard include path (/usr/include). Looking for other symbols in files on that path works OK, so I guess the problem is not with the include path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [getaddrinfo_a](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getaddrinfo_a.3.html) man page, the function requires `libanl` at link time. Try setting `CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES` before invoking `check_symbol_exists`:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE)
list(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES anl)
check_symbol_exists(getaddrinfo netdb.h HAVE_GETADDRINFO_A)
```

Comment: Small nit: `getaddrinfo` should be `getaddrinfo_a` in check_symbol_exists.